# Как вытащить нужное значение из запроса?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Когда боту приходит фотография в сообщении, он выдает такой результат запроса:

```
{"type":"message_new","object":{"id":21,"date":1549999669,"out":0,"user_id":XXX,"read_state":0,"title":"","body":"","attachments":[{"type":"photo","photo":{"id":XXX,"album_id":-3,"owner_id":XXX,"photo_75":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c847124\/v847124220\/19df30\/BRfTwvsNzIY.jpg","photo_130":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c847124\/v847124220\/19df31\/LKbwyjwb1Ag.jpg","photo_604":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c847124\/v847124220\/19df32\/IUsQgkOm1zM.jpg","photo_807":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c847124\/v847124220\/19df33\/LHknGn3O8_s.jpg","photo_1280":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c847124\/v847124220\/19df34\/Z19Mgr2bifI.jpg","width":647,"height":960,"text":"","date":1549999667,"access_key":"ddcefea2de81b39bd4"}}]},"group_id":XXX}
```

Чтобы вытащить информацию о отправителе сообщения (user_id), и делаю так:

```
$user_id = $data->object->user_id;
```

Но как мне вытащить ссылку на фотографию (photo_75)? Она получается там идет в массиве... который тоже в массиве вроде...

Comment: ну тяните цепочку, пока не доберётесь до нужного

Answer (score 1):

```
$photo_75 = $result->object->attachments[0]->photo->photo_75;
```

Answer (score 1):

Если проще работать с массивами, то можно эту строку представить как многомерный массив, через $array = json_decode($string, true); и работать уже с массивом

```
$photo = $array['object']['attachments'][0]['photo']['photo_75'];
```